# Rename/Adding extension the content in text file

Tags: terminal, rename

I have list of data in a text file that looks like this:

2116571574

2116571583

2116572143

and I want to add ".ok" at the end of each line to look like this:

2116571574.ok

2116571583.ok

2116572143.ok

Is there a possibility that this can be done via Terminal? Im using MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v'RS=\n+' '{print $0 ".ok" }' myfile
```

You need awk on a terminal for this

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you.